# How can I read two files from command line in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line, stdin

How would one be able to do this? I know you have to use <>.I already tried giving it a shot,but it might just because I am on Windows.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the `open` function to open the file *then* read the files?

Comment: My program has to be able to get the file names from command line.

Example:

./program.pl file1 file2

Answer (score 4):

```
# run as:
#       perl my_script1.pl file1 file2
my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;
open my $fh1, '<', $file1;
open my $fh2, '<', $file2;
while (<$fh1>) {
    ... do something with $_ from $file1 ...
}
while (<$fh2>) {
    ... do something with $_ from $file2 ...
}
close $fh1;
close $fh2;
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows,I am pretty sure it will work on Linux though,thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will work on Windows, too. Can you be more specific about how it doesn't work?

Comment: Works fine on Windows. Maybe your file associations are broken.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state whether you need to treat the files differently or not.  If not, then you can just use `<>` without needing to call `open` explicitly.

```
while (<>) {
  # Process $_
}
```

will work fine.  When it gets to the end of the first file, `<>` will continue on with reading the second file.  And so on until it runs out of files to read.